Group elements in dataframe and show them in chronological order
Consider the following dataframe, where Date is in the format DD-MM-YYY:
Date        Time      Table
01-10-2000  13:00:03  B
01-10-2000  13:00:04  A
01-10-2000  13:00:05  B
01-10-2000  13:00:06  A
01-10-2000  13:00:07  B
01-10-2000  13:00:08  A

How can I 1) group the observations by Table, 2) sort the rows according to Date and Time within each group, 3) show the groups in chronological order according to Date and Time of their first observation?
Date        Time      Table
01-10-2000  13:00:03  B
01-10-2000  13:00:05  B
01-10-2000  13:00:07  B
01-10-2000  13:00:04  A
01-10-2000  13:00:06  A
01-10-2000  13:00:08  A


Input data:
data = {
    'Date': ['01-10-2000', '01-10-2000', '01-10-2000', '01-10-2000', '01-10-2000', '01-10-2000'],
    'Time': ['13:00:03', '13:00:04', '13:00:05', '13:00:06', '13:00:07', '13:00:08'],
    'Table': ['B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


There are multiple moving parts here and it's verging on "multiple questions in one". To start, do you know how to convert strings to datetime? Do that first so that the question is simpler. For one thing, the date format is totally irrelevant to the problem.

Use groupby.transform and numpy.lexsort:
date = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']+' '+df['Time'])

out = df.iloc[np.lexsort([
    date,
    df['Table'],
    date.groupby(df['Table']).transform('min')
])]

Alternatively, using an intermediate column:
date = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']+' '+df['Time'])

out = (df.assign(date=date, min_date=date.groupby(df['Table']).transform('min'))
         .sort_values(by=['min_date', 'Table', 'date'])
         .drop(columns=['date', 'min_date'])
     )

Output:
         Date      Time Table
0  01-10-2000  13:00:03     B
2  01-10-2000  13:00:05     B
4  01-10-2000  13:00:07     B
1  01-10-2000  13:00:04     A
3  01-10-2000  13:00:06     A
5  01-10-2000  13:00:08     A


# Sort by Date and Time
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'] + ' ' + df['Time'], format='%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')
df_sorted = df.sort_values('DateTime')

# Find the first occurrence of each Table group
first_occurrences = df_sorted.groupby('Table', as_index=False).first()

# Sort Table groups according to the Date and Time of their first occurrence
table_order = first_occurrences.sort_values('DateTime')['Table']

# Create categorical version of 'Table' specifying the order of the categories
df_sorted['Table_cat'] = pd.Categorical(df_sorted['Table'], categories=table_order, ordered=True)

# Sort the dataframe
result = df_sorted.sort_values(['Table_cat', 'DateTime'])
result = result.reset_index(drop=True).drop('Table_cat', axis=1)


Instead of the groupby, pd.Categorical etc you could just create the DateTime column then use result = df.sort_values(['Table', 'DateTime'], ascending = [False, True]).drop('DateTime', axis=1) which gives the expected output.

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
data = {
    'Date': ['01-10-2000', '01-10-2000', '01-10-2000', '01-10-2000', '01-10-2000', '01-10-2000'],
    'Time': ['13:00:03', '13:00:04', '13:00:05', '13:00:06', '13:00:07', '13:00:08'],
    'Table': ['B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
'''
         Date      Time Table
0  01-10-2000  13:00:03     B
1  01-10-2000  13:00:04     A
2  01-10-2000  13:00:05     B
3  01-10-2000  13:00:06     A
4  01-10-2000  13:00:07     B
5  01-10-2000  13:00:08     A
'''
 
res = df.iloc[
    np.lexsort(
        (pd.to_datetime(df['Date'] + ' ' + df['Time']), df['Table'])
    )#lex
    ].reset_index(drop=True)
print(res)
'''
         Date      Time Table
0  01-10-2000  13:00:04     A
1  01-10-2000  13:00:06     A
2  01-10-2000  13:00:08     A
3  01-10-2000  13:00:03     B
4  01-10-2000  13:00:05     B
5  01-10-2000  13:00:07     B
'''

